# Killing a windows process based on running time with script

Tags: windows, script

I would to make a script to killtask a windows process / processes(childs) that runs for more than 25 hours, so I can task schedule it to run every 2 days: if an application runs for more than 25h = killtask;  to discard the resources consumed by applications.
I don't know what applications can occur.
The issue: i'm a splendid baby in scripting :|
Can someone help? Thank you in  advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a function of Task Scheduler.

Create your task in task scheduler and set it to automatically end after 25 hours.

Keep in mind, when you specify after how many hours you want the task to end, you only get a combobox with some predefined answers. You can just select one, like 12 hours, and then alter the value to make it 25, and it will work.

Comment: True, but this means I need to know what applications are running on that computer, which I don't...I thinked for a script in the idea of a "watchdog" and forget about it :)

Comment: So you want this script to kill every task that runs for more than 25 hours? You do realize that this will wreck havoc, as it basically means the entire computer is shutdown after 25 hours of runtime?